# Calculate $\int_C (\cos(z)+i) \, dz$ along the path $z(\theta) = \tfrac{\pi}{4} e^{i \theta}$, $\theta \in [0,\pi]$

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration, cauchy-integral-formula

I had this problem on my exam yesterday and would like to see how others would approach this problem. It just seemed like a lot of calculation for how much time I had, which makes me wonder if there is a different, simpler approach.

> Integrate $f(z)=\cos(z)+i$, where $z(\theta)=\frac{\pi}{4}e^{\theta i}$ on $0\le \theta \le \pi$.

My approach was to use the Cauchy integral formula. 
$$ \begin{align*} \int_C f(z) \, dz& =\int_{0}^\pi f[(\theta)]z'(\theta)\, d\theta \\ f[z(\theta)] &=\cos \left(\frac{\pi}{4}e^{\theta i} \right)+i \ \ \text{and} \ \ z'(\theta)=\frac{\pi}{4} i e^{\theta i} \\ \Rightarrow  \int_C f(z)\, dz &= \int_{0}^\pi \left(\cos \left(\frac{\pi}{4}e^{\theta i} \right)+i \right)\left( \frac{\pi}{4} i e^{\theta i} \right)\, d\theta  \\ &= \frac{\pi}{4} i \int_{0}^\pi e^{i \theta}\cos \left(\frac{\pi}{4}  e^{\theta i} \right) \, d\theta-\frac{\pi}{4} \int_0^\pi e^{i\theta}\, d\theta \end{align*}$$

From here, I just evaluated the two integrals, performing integration by parts twice on the first integral. Is this the correct approach to this problem, does it work? Is there a simpler way to go about it?

Thank you!

================================================

Εdit: I just wanted to finish out the problem using the CIF.

From where I left off, 
$$ \int_C f(z)dz= \frac{\pi}{4} i \int_{0}^\pi e^{i \theta}\cos \left(\frac{\pi}{4}  e^{\theta i} \right) \, d\theta-\frac{\pi}{4} \int_0^\pi e^{i\theta}\, d\theta $$

Splitting the integral up, we have

$$ \frac{\pi}{4} \int_0^\pi e^{i\theta}\, d\theta = \frac{\pi}{4} \bigg[-ie^{i\theta}\bigg]_0^\pi = -\frac{\pi}{4}i(e^{i\pi}-e^0)=-\frac{\pi}{4} i((-1)-1)=\frac{\pi}{2} i $$
and
$$\frac{\pi}{4} i \int_{0}^\pi e^{i \theta}\cos \left(\frac{\pi}{4}  e^{\theta i} \right) \, d\theta, \\ \text{Let} \ \ u=e^{i\theta} \Rightarrow du=ie^{i\theta}; \ \text{when} \ \theta=\pi, \ u=-1 \ \text{and when} \ \theta=0, \ u=1 \\ \therefore  \frac{\pi}{4} i \int_{1}^{-1}u\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{4}u\right)du=\frac{\pi}{4}\left[ -\frac{4}{\pi} \sin\left(\frac{\pi}{4}u\right)u\bigg|_1^{-1}+\frac{4}{\pi} \int_1^{-1}\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{4}u\right)du\right] \\ =-2\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{4}\right)+\left( \cos\left( -\frac{\pi}{4} \right)-\cos\left( \frac{\pi}{4} \right)\right)=-\frac{2\sqrt2}{2}=-\sqrt2$$
So, 
$$   \int_C f(z)dz= \frac{\pi}{4} i \int_{0}^\pi e^{i \theta}\cos \left(\frac{\pi}{4}  e^{\theta i} \right) \, d\theta-\frac{\pi}{4} \int_0^\pi e^{i\theta}\, d\theta =-\sqrt2-\frac{\pi}{2}i       $$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The mapping

$$z \mapsto f(z) := \cos(z) + i$$

is holomorphic and therefore

$$\int_{\gamma} f(z) \, dz = 0$$

for any closed curve $\gamma$. In particular,

$$\int_C f(z) \, dz + \int_{-\pi/4}^{\pi/4} f(t) \, dt = 0,$$

i.e.

$$\int_C f(z) \, dz = - \int_{-\pi/4}^{\pi/4} f(t) \, dt = - \bigg[ -\sin(t)+it \bigg]_{t=-\pi/4}^{\pi/4} = -\sqrt{2}-i \frac{\pi}{2}.$$

Comment: Shoot, I got it wrong. Why doesn't my approach work?

Comment: How did you arrive at third equality? It seems to me you parameterized curve $C'$ such that $C\cup C'$ is circle of radius $\pi/4$ but what I descrive doesn't give your result

Comment: @user160738 No, $C \cup C'$ is not a circle. The curve $C'$ is just the straight line connecting $-\pi/4$ and $\pi/4$, i.e. $$z(\theta) = \theta, \qquad \theta \in \left[- \frac{\pi}{4}, \frac{\pi}{4} \right].$$

Comment: @Kosta I think your approach is correct and should give the same result.
 Perhaps there is a mistake somewhere in your calculations?

Comment: @Kosta your approach should give the same answer.  It's just a brute force attack not exploiting the path independence which saz did so nicely.

Comment: Hmm, I probably did make a mistake. My answer was definitely not that. I'll post Mt exact solution once I get my exam back to pick out any mistakes. Thanks for your help

Comment: @Kosta You are welcome.

Comment: I did the problem out and posted the finished CIF approach in the edit I made. I must have made some miscalculation on my exam that gave me a different answer.